# awk to count found and output strings not found

Tags: awk

I am not getting the correct output using the below `awk`.  Basically if the string in `file1` is not found in `file2` it is printed as "missing".  If the string is found it is counted as "found".  As of now, a file that is zero bytes is returned. Thank you :).

**file1**

```
A2M
A4GALT
AGRN
```

**file2**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'[ -]' 'NR == FNR { seen[$0]; next } !seen[$6]++ { n++ }
> END { print n " ids found"; for (i in seen) if (!seen[i]) print i " missing" }' file1 file2
```

**desired output**

```
1 id found (`since the AGRN string was found`)
A2M missing
A4GALT missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat m.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]+|-" }
NR == FNR { seen[$0]; next }
$6 in seen { found[$6]; delete seen[$6] }
END { print length(found) " ids found"
      for (i in seen) print i " missing" }

$ awk -f m.awk file1 file2
1 ids found
A4GALT missing
A2M missing
```

Comment: Your welcome. Not much by the way of explanation, but please let me know if you have any questions about it.